# Authentication using ServiceStack 4.5.14

Tags: c#, authentication, servicestack

I'm working off of the SocialBootstrap API example (using ServiceStack 4.5.14) and trying to get authentication to work. Registration works fine, the user account get's created in the DB without any problem, but when I try to use the newly created user to login I get "Invalid Username or Password". When I step through my code the correct username and password are being passed. My code on signup looks like:

```
using (var authService = HostContext.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>())
{
    //authenticate with servicestack
    var response = authService.Authenticate(new Authenticate
    {
        provider = CredentialsAuthProvider.Name,
        UserName = model.Username,
        Password = model.Password,
        RememberMe = model.RemeberMe
    });

    ...
```

It hits the authenticate method and then goes to:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connStr, //ConnectionString in Web.Config
        SqlServerDialect.Provider)
    {
        ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
    });
```

in AppHost.cs. After this it throws the "Invalid username or password error".
I can't figure out why it won't authenticate. With the exception of using SQL Server instead of Postgres the code is basically identical to the example. I know my SQL connection works and the connection string is OK because registration works flawlessly. I just am at a loss to see what else I can do to make the login work. Can anyone shed some light on what I've done wrong or something else I can try to find my error?

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried the [SocialBootstrapApi](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/SocialBootstrapApi) project. Installed the [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer/) package, replaced the `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` to use SQL Server:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connString, SqlServerDialect.Provider)
    {
        ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
    });
```

Then was able register a new User with Email `test@gmail.com` and Password `test` which logs straight in:

[image]

Logging out and Signing In also works as expected.

Comment: Originally i was using 4.0.56. I just upgraded to 5.0.2. Is there anything in 5.02 that would keep this from working? Am I handling authentication right? I know I'm passing in the right username and password in the authService.Authenticate method, but it just fails. I'm not sure what I can do to debug the problem. Is there something I need to check to make sure it's set up correctly?

Comment: @user2033791 I've upgraded all SocialBootstrapApi deps in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/SocialBootstrapApi/commit/eef1e8d50de8216bffacd058a59863125e566242) and it continues to work as expected. If you [uncomment the first line](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/AppHost.cs#L1) and replace the connectionString with your server it should work. If it fails try deleting all UserAuth tables to have ServiceStack start from a clean slate.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: So I've downloaded the Mvc project: https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/tree/master/src/Mvc. When I try to use the code:

    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
                new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connStr, SqlServerDialect.Provider)
                {
                    ConnectionFilter = x => new ProfiledDbConnection(x, Profiler.Current)
                });

It complains about ProfiledDbConnection and says it doesn't exist. It also looks like the MVC project is missing all of it's ServiceStack references. What assembly do I need to load to to get ProfiledDbConnection?

Comment: @user2033791 From v5 ProfiledDbConnection is now in [ServiceStack.NetFramework](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.0.0#net-framework-specific-features). I've just upgraded all ServiceStack Deps in that project so if you fetch latest from master it should build + run.

Comment: Thanks it's all working now. I made it match the mvc project and it started working.